# FFMPEG, the penultimate image from the .txt file doesn't show in the video

Tags: shell, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to create a video from the images using `ffmeg`. Actually, the creating of the video works but there is a small problem. I have a text file with the names of the images (paths) which I'm using in the video. The file looks like this

```
file 'image1.jpg'
file 'image2.jpg'
file 'image3.jpg'
file 'image4.jpg'
file 'image5.jpg'
```

And the ffmeg command is following

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -f concat -safe 0 -i imagenames.txt -i some_audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -vf fps=30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 output.mp4
```

This video should keep the frame on every image for 5 seconds. But the problem is the penultimate image `( image4 in this case )` is not being shown in the video. So, it keeps on `image3` 10 seconds and moves to `image5`

So, the video in seconds looks like this

`[image1] -> [image2] -> [image3] -> [image4] -> [image5]
   5sec        5sec       10sec        0sec        5sec`

And the problem is not with the `image4` exactly. In case of swapping `image3` and `image4`, the video will skip `image3`

`[image1] -> [image2] -> [image4] -> [image3] -> [image5]
   5sec        5sec       10sec        0sec        5sec`

Hope you'll have any suggestions to fix this issue

Comment: Share the readout for `ffmpeg -i filename` for all images.

Comment: if you swap the order of images (eg swap image3 and image4) does it still impact the penultimate one, or is image4 still the problem?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal , yeah, it skips the penultimate image only. So, the problem doesn't related to images

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, in case of swapping ( image3 and image4 ) it skips image3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If anyone will ever have such a problem***

The issue in my case was that the `height` of the last image ( `image5` ) was different than all other images. Not sure how that was affected to the video slides, but the issue is gone after having all 5 images with the same width and height.

Hope this will help anyone in the future and you'll not spend a week looking for a bug -_-